# database storing multiple types of data, but need unique ids globally

Tags: mysql, database, api, rest, identifier

a while ago, i asked about how to implement a REST api.  i have since made headway with that, but am trying to fit my brain around another idea.

in my api, i will have multiple types of data, such as people, events, news, etc.

now, with REST, everything should have a unique id. this id, i take it, should be unique to the whole system, and not just each type of data.

for instance, there should not be a person with id #1 and a news item with id of #1. ultimately, these two things would be given different ids altogether: person #1 with unique id of #1 and news item #1 with unique id #2, since #1 was taken by a person.

in a database, i know that you can create primary keys that automatically increment.  the problem is, usually you have a table for each data "type", and if you set the auto increment for each table individually, you will get "duplicate" ids (yes, the ids are still unique in their own table, but not the whole DB).

is there an easy way to do this? for instance, can all of these tables be set to work off of one incrementer (the only way i could think of how to put it), or would it require creating a table that holds these global ids, and ties them to a table and the unique id in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a GUID, they will be unique everywhere (for all intents and purposes anyway).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: wow, quick reply! i see the point of the guid or uuid identifiers, but how about this problem:

if i know the guid or uuid, do i have to query each table to find it, or is there a special SQL statement that will determine what table it is in?

Comment: You will know where the guid lives only if you add a trigger to each table which writes a record out to a GUID_tracking table: e.g.  your_guid_value|your_table_name.

Comment: ok, the pieces are falling in place now. this all makes sense. i have never used, nor heard of triggers for mysql, but will look into these, as well as uuids and guids.

thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

+1 for UUIDs (note that GUID is a particular Microsoft implementation of a [UUID standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier))

There is a built-in function [uuid()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) for generating UUID as text. You may probably prefix it with table name so that you may easily recognize it later.

Each call to `uuid()` will generate you a fresh new value (as text). So with the above method of prefixing, the `INSERT` query may look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (CONCAT('my_table-', UUID()), ...)
```

And don't forget to make this column varchar of large enough size and of course create an index for it.

Comment: interesting way to store the link to the table...

this UUID() function, i guess it should be used when doing a SQL INSERT, like so:

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (UUID(), ...)

assuming the UUID was the first field in the table?

Comment: Yes, each call to UUID() will generate you a fresh new value (as text). So with the above method of prefixing, the query becomes like this: `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (CONCAT('my_table-', UUID()), ...)`.

Comment: And don't forget to make this column varchar of large enough size and of course create an index for it.

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but just wondering: theoretically, a UUID should be large and random enough that a duplicate will never be made, however, a duplicate is still possible. so, i can assume that using the example you posted, i would still want to put some kind of error detection in my web scripts, just in case the 100 trillionth DB transaction causes a Primary Key constraint issue...

Comment: You should definitely put a primary key constraint and handle any SQL error in your app, but the collision of UUIDs is [unlikely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Comment: that is what i figured, just wanted to make sure.  thanks for the great help on this!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't hesitate to vote up and select my answer ;)

Comment: Also I'd recommend you to have primary key as plain auto_increment integer, and uuid just as another unique, not null and indexed column. There are [arguments](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/) about the performance on large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

> now, with REST, everything should have a unique id. this id, i take
>   it, should be unique to the whole system, and not just each type of
>   data.

That's simply not true. Every resource needs to have a unique *identifier*, yes, but in an HTTP system, for example, that means a unique URI. `/people/1` and `/news/1` are unique URI's. There is *no* benefit (and in fact quite a lot of pain, as you are discovering) from constraining the system such that `/news/1` has to instead be `/news/0983240-2309843-234802/` in order to avoid conflict.

Comment: yes, what you say makes sense, however, i was looking to implement a more facebook like api; with facebook, (if i am not mistaken) you can simply pass the api the id of some object, whether it is a user, application, etc, and it will spit back the information of that.  therefore, i would assume that they would need some kind of global mapping scheme to determine what kind of object an id relates to, as well as keeping everything unique in the system.  thanks for the insight though.